# Unregister a viewset from drf router

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two separate apps `Product` and `Tag` which i used another app `Product_tags` to connect them together. in this way, if one of them don't exists, another one will work fine. inside `Product_tags`, I created a new `TagProductSerializer` which inherits `ProductSerializer` and I just added a new field named tag in fields list. 
**product_tags/serializers.py**:

```
class TagProductSerializer(ProductSerializer):
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tag.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'tags',
        ]
    #...
```

and I did the same with `Product` viewset
**product_tags/views.py**

```
class TagProductViewset(ProductViewset):
    serializer_class  = SocialProductSerializer
```

and in my `product_tags/urls.py` I imported my `Product` router and i wanted to register my product viewset again for router. and there is my problem:

**product/urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('product', ProductViewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**product_tags/urls.py** (PROBLEM)

```
from product.urls import router
from .views import TagProductViewset

router.unregister('product') # I'm looking for something like this
router.register('product',TagProductViewset)
```

NOTE: I want to show the tags when getting product and because of that, I don't want to use different url for getting tag (e.g "api/product/tags/")

**First Try:**
I tried to register the 'product' again (`router.register('product',SocialProductViewset)`) but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem but i forgot to say that here. I just created new router in my `product_tags/urls.py` and then I added it in `urlpatterns` inside of `project/urls.py` at top of my original product router.
**product_tags/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import TagProductViewset

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('product',TagProductViewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include("product_tags.urls")),
    path('api/v1/', include("product.urls")),
]
```